# Convert random positive values of an array to negative

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm a JS newcomer. I have a scrambled array of numbers and need to convert random positive values of the array into negative. At that point I only know how to randomize the array:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
myArray.sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
})
```

But need the result look something like this:
[8,-2,3,9,-5,-1,4,7,6,-10]

Please suggest. Thank you!

Comment: Iterate over the array, flip a coin and negate the number for heads. What specifically are you having problems with? Do you know how to iterate over an array? How to negate a number?

Comment: Felix, thanks! I don't know how to randomly negate the number for heads, but will look it up.

Comment: Don't use this code to shuffle. The result is not guaranteed by the spec.

Answer (score 1):

```
myArray.forEach(function(i,j){

if(i>0){

  var negative=i*(-1);/*convert your positive values to negative*/
  myArray[j]=negative;

}

})
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified Fisher–Yates shuffle to randomly negate the item

```
function shuffle2(arr) {
    var i, j, e;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) { // for every index
        j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - i)); // choose random index to right
        e = arr[i]; // swap with current index
        arr[i] = arr[i + j];
        arr[i + j] = e;
        if (.5 > Math.random()) // then, randomly
            arr[i] = -arr[i]; // flip to negative
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Now can do

```
shuffle2(myArray); // [-5, 2, 6, -7, -10, 1, 3, -4, -9, -8]
```

---

Please note if you were to stop the loop at `arr.length - 1` you will need a final random flip outside of the loop for the last index

Comment: Thank you, Paul S., this is great and the comments are very helpful too

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your array using [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get random +/- like this:

```
myArray = myArray.map(function(item) {
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? item : -item; // random +/-
});
```

Map function does not modify your array but only returns new mapped one (so you have to reassign it or assign to a new variable).

Comment: It may be helpful to explain that `.map` returns a new array.

Comment: From the example, I think OP wants to shuffle the array as well. This won't do it.

Comment: That shuffle code won't work. It's not guaranteed to terminate. Here's code that will work, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274339/how-can-i-shuffle-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, will use the suggested solution to shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a second random number for positiv / negative (Flipping coin):

```
var pos = Math.floor(Math.random()*10) % 2;
var num = Math.random() * 10;
var result;
// pos will evaluate false if it is 0
// or true if it is 1
result = pos ? num : -num;

return result;
```

Comment: please note `pos` will always be in the range `[0..1)`

Comment: Ah true i forgot about that, hold on.

Answer (score 0):

As you are a new comer this is the easiest way. Used [for loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) and [Math.floor()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp)

1. First randomize the array.
2. Use `math.random()*myArray.length` and `for loop` to generate a random number and change the value of the index corresponding to the number value eg-

```js
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  var arrVal = myArray[Math.floor( Math.random()*myArray.length);]
if(arrVal > 0){
  arrVal = arrVal*(-1);
};
  };
```